# Emacs: Prevent auto-fill mode breaking lines in latex \text{...} inline commands

Tags: emacs

The latex package polyglossia allows for correct typesetting of foreign languages: it provides an inline command of the form `\text[foreign_language]{...}`, such as `\textspanish{Soy el hijo de Fernando}`.

Since I use Emacs, I have to prevent auto-fill mode from breaking up those code blocks: for example, ending a line with `\textspanish{Soy el`, and beginning the next line with `hijo de Fernando}`. When auto-fill mode breaks lines in this way, the exporter gets confused.

I tried creating a function to add as hook to `fill-nobreak-predicate`, but my knowledge of regular expressions and elips is not good enough. This is how far I got:

```
(defun foreign-language-nobreak-p ()
     (or    (looking-at "[[[:space:]]\|[[:print:]]].*}")
            (save-excursion 
              (skip-chars-backward " \t")
              (unless (bolp)
                (backward-char 1)
                (looking-at ".*\\text")))))


(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'foreign-language-nobreak-p)
```

Any ideas on what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for pointing out `fill-nobreak-predicate`. Never heard about it in my first 23 years of Emacs.

Regarding your regexp question, I'd like to mention the function `regexp-opt` which takes a list of strings and builds an efficient regexp that matches those strings:

```
(defvar foreign-lang-re
  (regexp-opt
   '("\\textspanish{"
     "\\textrussian{"
     "\\textfrench{")))
```

If you factor out the supported languages into yet another variable, you could also build the list of strings with a loop, adding `\text` and the trailing `{`.

If your heuristic would be stable enough that you don't want auto filling to kick in when there is just the opening command somewhere on the current line, you could use `thing-at-point` like so:

```
(defun foreign-language-nobreak-p ()
  (string-match
   foreign-lang-re
   (thing-at-point 'line t)))
```

This does not work when you closed the command already with a `}`. For that to work better, you'd need to search backward from your current point for the optimized regexp and forward for a closing curly brace, limiting the search to `(bolp)` and `(eolp)` respectively. This would get really hairy if you start to use other commands with curly braces inside the `\textspanish` command, though.

Hope that makes sense and helps a bit.

Comment: I hereby put the above code also under the GPLv3 in addition to the StackOverflow default of CC-BY-SA